# HOw do you remove duplicate values from a single excel cell

Tags: excel, powerquery

How do you remove duplicate values from a single excel cell (A1) using power query

**For example:**

Anish,Anish,Prakash,Prakash,Prakash,Anish~,Anish~

**Result wanted as like:**

Anish,Prakash,Anish~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates within Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897429/remove-duplicates-within-excel-cell)

Comment: parse it into separate cells, remove duplicates, concatenate it back to one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Power Query, you can refer to a single cell in the current workbook if it is a named range. You could then use something like this, to list the distinct values:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MyCell"]}[Content],
    #"Split List" = Text.Split(Source{0}[Column1],","),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = List.Distinct(#"Split List"),
    #"Combine Values" = Text.Combine(#"Removed Duplicates",",")
in
    #"Combine Values"
```

Comment: Thank you much. this worked for me. Kind regards,Anish

Comment: @anish.rossvilla if this solution worked for you, then you should use the "tick" to accept it...

Answer (score 0):

I am new to M code.  However, for others who might has similar experience as me, I studied a little bit and I think the following might be easier for others to understand:

```
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values1", "Split1", each Text.Split([#"Cust"],",")),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "RemoveDuplicate1", each List.Distinct([#"Split1"])),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "CombineValue1", each Text.Combine([#"RemoveDuplicate1"],",")),
```

Just simply copy above code in `Advanced Editor`, and change the column name respectively.  In my case, the column name is `Cust, Split1, RemoveDuplicate1,CombineValue1`.  Of course, the added column name might also be different.
Basically, the 3 rows means we need to create 3 columns, if we manually create 3 columns, then we just need to copy and paste the code after "each" of each row of above. 
See below:

[image]

Comment: Bold giant sentences are not needed, also thanks... simply give the answer: "for others who might has similar experience as me, I studied a little bit and I think the following might be easier for others to understand:" without BOLD. I suggest to edit your post and improve the formatting and add image description. Keep doing